# Passing data from controller to view Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, templates, variable-assignment

I am trying to pass data to view but it gives me that error:
Undefined variable: data

Controller:

```
public function article($page=1)
{           
    $info = array(
        "module_name" => $this->module_name,
        "view_name" => "cms/cms_view", // your view path
        "error_msg" => "",  
        "error_type" => "", 
        "data" => array(
        'content'=>$this->cms_model->get_cms($page),
        'test'=>'Hello world'

        ), //data which will be sent to view
    );
    $this->loadview->view($info);
}
```

Model:

```
 public function get_cms($page)
    {
        $query = $this->db->get_where('article', array('art_id' => $page),1);
        return $query->row();
    }
```

View:

```
<?php
        echo $data->content;
        ?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable"  and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Answer (score 2):

Note the last line.

Controller:

```
public function article($page=1) {

    $info = array(
        "module_name" => $this->module_name,
        "view_name" => "cms/cms_view", // your view path
        "error_msg" => "",  
        "error_type" => "", 
        "data" => array(
            'content'=>$this->cms_model->get_cms($page),
            'test'=>'Hello world'

        ), //data which will be sent to view
    );
    $this->load->view('view_name', $info);
}
```

More info about how to load a view [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html).

Comment: Thanks but this didn't solve the problem. 
and if info isn't seen by the cms_view then why when I try to echo test in the view, it's displayed correctly :S.

Comment: $info isn't visible, but $module_name, $view_name, etc. $data['content'] and $data['test'] should be visible.

Comment: i have read the article about how to pass data From Controller To View In CodeIgniter https://www.cloudways.com/blog/how-to-pass-data-in-codeigniter/

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem may be in your view. The $data variable is setup as an array in your controller but you are treating it like an object. Try using

```
<?php
     echo $data["content"];
?>
```

in the view instead and see if that corrects your issue.